# Prevent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE from saving a picture

Tags: android, android-intent, photos

I am using an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent` to take photos, which I then manipulate.

I want to save **only** the final image. How can I prevent photos from being saved immediately after photo is taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to copy the image returned in the result Intent and then use a ContentResolver to delete the original image.  The different OEMs, of course, have different camera implementations.  The procedure I described has worked with all of them from my testing.

This is assuming that there's some reason that you can't just manipulate the original image and write over it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a third-party app to take the picture for you:

- The third-party app *has* to save the picture, because otherwise it cannot get the picture to you
- The third-party app can do whatever else it wants, because it was written by somebody else, and they can do what they want

If that is unacceptable, do not use third-party apps to take the picture for you.

Comment: I am not. Just built-in Camera app.

Comment: @Fengson: Since you did not write "built-in Camera app", that is a third-party app from the standpoint of you and your app.